# Java documentation practice for overriding methods whose return type is subclass of overridden method's return type

Tags: java, javadoc, code-documentation

I am writing Javadoc for a new package where I am facing the dilemma mentioned in the title.

I have base class method defined as,

```java
class Vector<E> {
  ..
  public abstract Vector<E> add(Vector<E> v);
  ..
}
```

The overriding method is defined as,

```java
class IntVector extends Vector<Integer> {
  ..
  @Override
  public IntVector add(Vector<Integer> v) {
  ..
  }
```

The overriding method does not change the behavior except for the return type. I know that redundant documentation is not desirable for overridden methods. However in this case it makes sense for the overriding method to have its own documentation, at least for the return type. What is the best practice for such situations? Just copy the specification over or is there a good way to avoid duplication?

Comment: What do you need to say about it? "Returns an IntVector"? Is that really worth calling out, beyond the statement of the return type?

Comment: I want the users to know the return type of IntVector.add(v) is IntVector so they can use IntVector for the return value.

Comment: If the user is using an `IntVector` then their IDE will show them that the return type is an `IntVector`.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, if there is nothing special about the different return type and you only want to point out that it is different, then there is normally no need to do this explicitly. The javadoc and the IDE code completion will indicate that the return type is different.

However, if you want to add additional information, then you can take a look at [method comment inheritance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/javadoc.html#CHDFAGJH):

> When a main description, or @return, @param, or @throws tag is missing from a method comment, the javadoc command copies the corresponding main description or tag comment from the method it overrides or implements (if any).

So in your case you could write:

```
/**
 * @return A verify special IntVector
 */
@Override
public IntVector add(Vector<Integer> v) {
    ...
}
```

And it would copy all missing information, such as the main description and the documentation for the `v` parameter from the overridden method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can you please elaborate on "The javadoc and the IDE code completion will indicate that the return type is different", the javadoc part? Right now (no comment in overriding method) the user sees add() method in "methods declared in base class", which indicates the return type is Vector<E>.

Comment: I cannot reproduce what you are describing. When I run `javadoc -sourcepath src -d docs -subpackages my` (in Java 8 & 12), I see the overridden method listed under "Method Summary", even if the return type was not altered (not sure if this is intended). However, for me the section "Methods declared in" (also used by the Java SE 12 doc) is called "Methods inherited from" (like it is the case for the Java SE 8 doc).

Comment: @user1200373, do you use `--overridden-methods=summary`? If so then you are likely experiencing [JDK-8219147](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8219147).

Comment: You are exactly right, `--overridden-methods=summary` is used; and the bug you mentioned precludes javadoc to be generated for the overriding method when I use just @inheritDoc tag. The bug also gives me an example of similar situation in JDK library, and that's the convention I will follow.

Comment: As a side note - what I have observed it `--overridden-methods=summary` generates the "Methods declared in" section, whereas `--overridden-methods=detail` generates "Methods inherited from" section.